# How to define styleable and default attributes to accept both float and int (dp and wrap_content)

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-attributes

I'm working on an OpenSource lib as an alternative for the built-in android PopupMenu, in my lib I'd like to make everything customizable such that if you want to use it and change the popup colors/dimensions it becomes easy.

The full source code is here:
https://github.com/shehabic/Droppy/tree/styleable_ui

I'm few issues .. briefly I learned that to make your widget/custom view styleable you have to define 1-Custom View, 2-Styleable attributes, 3-Default values for such styleable attributes.
so I have the following xml files:

**res/droppy__attr.xml**

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Droppy">
        <attr name="droppyMenuItemTitleStyle" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="DroppyMenuItemTitle">
        <attr name="android:textColor"/>
        <attr name="android:minWidth"/>
        <attr name="android:minHeight"/>
        <attr name="android:layout_height"/>
        <attr name="android:layout_width"/>
        <attr name="android:layout_gravity"/>
        <attr name="android:gravity"/>
        <attr name="android:layout_weight"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resource>
```

**res/droppy__styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.DroppyDefaults" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="droppyMenuItemTitleStyle">@style/Droppy.DroppyMenuItemTitle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Droppy">
    </style>

    <style name="Droppy.DroppyMenuItemTitle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/darkgrey</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">128dp</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">30dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">end|center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    </style>
</resource>
```

**res/droppy__defaults.xml**

```
<resources>       
    <!-- Menu Item Title -->
    <color name="default_menu_item_title_textColor">@color/darkgrey</color>
    <dimen name="default_menu_item_title_minWidth">128dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="default_menu_item_title_minHeight">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="default_menu_item_title_layout_width">0dp</dimen>


    <!-- There's no easy way to set default values for the following -->
    <!--<float name="default_menu_item_title_layout_weight">1</float>-->
    <!--<item name="default_menu_item_title_layout_gravity">end|center_vertical</item>-->
    <!--<item name="default_menu_item_title_gravity">center_vertical</item>-->
</resources>
```

In the block above here's the 1st issue,
Now here's the code I use in my custom view:

**DroppyMenuItem.java**

```
public class DroppyMenuItemTitle extends TextView {

    public DroppyMenuItemTitle(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public DroppyMenuItemTitle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.droppyMenuItemTitleStyle);
    }

    public DroppyMenuItemTitle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        final int defaultWidth = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        final float defaultWeight = 1;

        final int defaultGravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
        final int defaultLayoutGravity = Gravity.END | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DroppyMenuItemTitle, defStyleAttr, 0);
        int width = (int) a.getDimension(R.styleable.DroppyMenuItemTitle_android_layout_width, defaultWidth);
        int height = a.getInt(R.styleable.DroppyMenuItemTitle_android_layout_height, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
        setGravity(a.getInt(R.styleable.DroppyMenuItemTitle_android_gravity, defaultGravity));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
        lp.width = width;
        lp.height = height;
        lp.weight = a.getFloat(R.styleable.DroppyMenuItemTitle_android_layout_weight, defaultWeight);
        lp.gravity = a.getInteger(R.styleable.DroppyMenuItemTitle_android_layout_gravity, defaultLayoutGravity);

        setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
```

---

As per the following line:

```
int width = (int) a.getDimension(R.styleable.DroppyMenuItemTitle_android_layout_width, defaultWidth);
```

if I use that customView and specify width as wrap_content or match_parent, it works fine as these are translated to -1 and -2.
But if specify it as XXdp (e.g. 20dp) it fails as the number now is actually a float not int

the error I get is as follows:

> E/AndroidRuntime(2940): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "20.0dip"

Comment: Where in your code are you setting that value?

Comment: here: https://github.com/shehabic/Droppy/blob/styleable_ui/samples/src/main/res/values/styles.xml#L14

Comment: I have written my answer, and if it still doesn't work then you should clean your project (if using eclipse) or do files > invalidate cashes & restart (in android studio)

Comment: why dont you use getDimensionPixelSize ?

Comment: @pskink yes you're right this probably should work, I even found a special method made for layout params I posted in the answer below

Comment: @pskink I'm afraid the method throws an exception with the values I mentioned and looking at android's source code, it doesn't seem to be a special version of getDimensionPixelSize, the code is so different, and it's not checking type as in detLayoutDimension

Comment: post your stack trace then

Comment: it's the same error above, no difference at the same line of code

Comment: post your stack trace

Comment: The stack trace: https://gist.github.com/shehabic/e6e4139a9d1c27ca559f
and the current file:
https://gist.github.com/shehabic/88210b5b9cd0c8613625
as the inherited value for layout_height = "wrap_content" and getDimensionPixelSize doesn't accept wrap_content / match_parent (as per my tries)

Comment: so it wants type: TYPE_DIMENSION = 0x05; but TYPE_FIRST_INT = 0x10; is passed, what attributes are you passing to obtainStyledAttributes ?

Comment: wrap_content (which is not accepted) as it's an int not dimen, and that's what I've been trying to say from the beginning

Comment: ok for testing try TypedArray.getType(int index) you should get one of TypedValue.TYPE_*, it should be TypedValue.TYPE_DIMENSION (value == 5), you can also see what is returned for "normal" android:layout_width for example